# I'm new and can't understand why an "Uncaught TypeError: number.split is not a function" is appearing when I add the while loop?

Tags: javascript

```
let number = "7465";
let number1 = 0;
let a = 0;
let b = 0;
```

defines the variable

```
while (number !== 6174) {
  a = number.split("").sort().join("");
  b = a.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Should sort the numbers but says .split is not a function

Comment: split is for strings only.  numbers have to be converted to a string if you want to use split on them

Answer (score 1):

`split` method can only be used with strings. And there was no `number--` in the while loop, which will lead to an infinite loop. Try the following code

```
let number = 7465
let number1 = 0;
let a = 0;
let b = 0;

while (number !== 6174) {
  a = number.toString().split("").sort().join("");
  b = a.split("").reverse().join("");
  number--
}
```